# Поднять сервер с нуля

Tags: сервер

Возникла необходимость заиметь собственный сервер. Основная его задача - работа с БД.Собственно, вопросы:

1. Какую ось ставить?
2. Какое серверное ПО?
3. Какую СУБД?
4. Как получить к нему доступ извне? (вообще говоря, подключение должно быть и напрямую по локалке, и из интернета)

P.S. Я предполагаю ставить `MySQL` (так как более-менее разбираюсь в ней).

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос. Частный вариант ответа: ставьте CentOS 6.2 и MySQL. Этого достаточно для описанной задачи.

Comment: Ubuntu Server, Debian.

Comment: Server не обязательно, даже более того - не желательно, т.к. селовек похоже привык к окнам, и в иксах ему работать будет проще

Comment: А железо-то имеется? Или в датацентре арендовать собираетесь?

Comment: Думаю вы будете смеяться, но от меня хотят, чтобы я сотворил "сервер" из третьего пентиума...

Comment: Семен, а вы хоть один Windows Server без "окон" видели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно рассуждать так - раз предпочитаете MySQL, то ставить WinServer, конечно можно, но все-таки лучше что-нибудь из Linux\Unix. Дистрибутивов множество, имхо, надо выбрать какой-то незаточенный под десктопное использование (GUI и т.п. нафиг).Чтобы получить доступ извне - пробросить порт, по которому будете подключаться к БД на маршрутизаторе (конечно же сменить с дефолтного)).

Answer (score 2):

1. Ту, которую лучше всего можете администрировать (не обязательно "серверную");
2. Не требуется;
3. Если знаете mysql, то конечно mysql;
4. Если предполагается прямой доступ к базе, то требуется "белый" ip-адрес, по нему можно получать доступ и из локалки.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут описано подробно про установку Debian x64: [Установка минимальной версии Debian Squeeze x64 с обновлением до последней версии (в картинках) + SSH + sudo](http://htf.net.ua/install-minimal-debian-squeeze-x64).

Также ставится и 32 битная ОС.

По данной статье Вы получите сервер с доступом по `SSH`.

После для установки `MySQL` надо ввести команду для установки "`apt-get install mysql-server-5.1`"

Ну а также чтоб было удобно работать с базами поставить `apache2` или `nginx + php` и поставить оболочку `phpMyAdmin` для работ с БД.

Доступ к серверу по SSH. Можно также установить и по FTP "`apt-get install proftpd`"

Третий пенек под виндовсом с БД `MySQL` это будет ужасно.В сторону `Ubuntu` тоже не рекомендую смотреть, эта ОС потребляет больше ресурсов чем `Debian`.

Answer (score 1):

Реально на этом железе можно сделать роутер, файлопомойку (при наличии достаточного дискового объёма), или небольшой почтовый сервер. Для тонких клиентов это железо абсолютно непригодно!

Исходя из конфигурации железа, винды там тоже абсолютно непригодны, надо копать в сторону [DSL](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) или чего-то подобного. И вот вам ещё в помощь: [Linux дистрибутивы для слабых машин](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=30990.0).

Comment: Спасибо! не ожидал, что хоть что-то можно будет сделать)

Answer (score 1):

1. Если у вас возникают такие вопросы, то, однозначно, лучше ставьте `ubuntu server` - т.к. у неё, пожалуй, самое сильное на данный момент комьюнити и вам проще будет решать проблемы на первых парАх
2. Для начала попробуйте сделать простенький конфиг в `iptables` или попытать счастья со скриптами-генераторами, скорее всего, этого хватит для начала
3. Ну раз знаете `MySQL`, то его и ставьте
4. Через `ssh`

Comment: Добавлю. Получить доступ извне можно при помощи webmin, хоть это и считается не по феншую. Но если в консольных командах линукса не силен - самое оно.Когда народ говорит про ssh - имеется ввиду консоль(черный экран). К ней в догон тебе лучше ставить mc (Midnight Commander). похож на виндовый Total Commander и имеет встроеный редактор. И все-таки сервер не советую.Захочется иксы - а нету.

Comment: зачем иксы на сервере?

Comment: Иранда, вам платят за то, что вы ставите в каждом ответе большие буквы вместо маленьких в начале предложения? :)

Comment: actionless, для удобства. Если бы человек был привычным к конфигурированию из терминала, такой вопрос просто бы не возник